# How can I update my existing record without losing the data?

Tags: mongodb, insert-update

I'm learning how to use mongodb command. I have an existing record to update with the following data:

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "exempt_location_tax" : "",
  "account_type" : "",
  "keys" : {
    "login_id" : "undefinedfgsfdg",
    "transaction_key" : "dsfgsdfgsdfgundefined"
  },
  "type" : "string"
}
```

I'm trying to update the `keys` field data using `db.collection_name.update({"_id":1},{$set:{"keys":{updatedTes:"string"}}})` it will update the document and first unset the existing data of the keys field and then set it with the coming data. But I want that the existing data remains there also with the new data.

Can anyone help me to build a query that will do that?

Comment: Do you want to add `updatedTes:"string"` as new property inside `keys` object?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
db.collection_name.update({"_id":1},{$set:{"keys.updatedTes":"string"}})
```